# ¿Porqué según el compilador que use imprime una cosa u otra?

Tags: c

Este programa lo que pretende es añadir un bit para que la cantidad de 1's sea par. Programo en VS Code y cuando lo compilé me puso por pantalla varias direcciones de memoria y lo demás bien
[image: Imagen de la compilación]

En cambio, cuando lo compilé en GDB Online el programa hacía lo que debía hacer. A continuación veréis la función que me genera el bit de paridad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del programa al completo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void RellenarArray(int *listaDinamica, int num);
void AnadirBitParidad(int *listaDinamica, int num);

int main(){
    int N = 10, *array; //N puede tomar cualquier valor

    array = (int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    if(array == NULL)
        printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria");
    else{
        RellenarArray(array, N);
        AnadirBitParidad(array, N);
    }    
    
    free(array);

    return 0;
}

void RellenarArray(int *listaDinamica, int num){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        *(listaDinamica + i) = rand()%2;
        printf("%i   ", *(listaDinamica + i));
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void AnadirBitParidad(int *listaDinamica, int num){
    int i, cont = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        if(*(listaDinamica + i) == 1)
            cont++;
    }

    listaDinamica = (int *)realloc(listaDinamica, num+1*sizeof(int));   //num+1 ya que queremos añadir 1 o 0 en funcion de la cantidad de 1's

    if(listaDinamica == NULL)
        printf("No se ha podido redimensionar el vector");
    else{
        if((cont%2) == 0)
            *(listaDinamica + num) = 0;
        else
            *(listaDinamica + num) = 1;

        for(i = 0; i <= num; i++)   //Para llegar al num+1, hay que poner <=
            printf("%i   ", *(listaDinamica + i));

    }
}
```

Comment: Aún dandole a cont el valor 0, sigue poniendo esos números aleatorios.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `cont` no es inicializado. Por lo tanto tiene un valor indeterminado.

Una de las formas de notarlo es que al ejecutar el código en varias ocasiones obtienes valores diferentes.

No pude confirmar que así sea, pero aparentemente gcc inicializa las variables por defecto en 0. Cosa que Visual Studio no hace y por eso obtienes resultados diferentes entre compiladores.

Probablemente estés recibiendo una advertencia de que la variable se usa sin inicializar. Sino, en [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) puedes recibirla agregando las opciones de compilación **-Wuninitialized** y **-Wmaybe-uninitialized**.

Intuyo que cont debería ser 0:

```
int i, cont = 0;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, desconocía que cada compilador hacía lo que quisiera, pero aun poniendo el cont = 0, sigue siendo el mismo problema. Y sí, cada vez que ejecuto el código aparecen numeros diferentes

Comment: @PabloRivero añade más código para que entendamos como lo estás ejecutando. Hay un estándar que los compiladores deben seguir. Solo que hay detalles que se le da la libertad al compilador de definir o simplemente no se dice nada al respecto. Por cierto, puedes expresar `*(listaDinamica + num)` como `listaDinamica[num]`.

Comment: Ya está editado la publicación y ya está el código ahí, siento las molestias.